# What tool would you choose for generating multiple C# files for WCF contract versioning?

Tags: c#, powershell, versioning

I have some breaking changes to WCF contracts and I want to be able to support two versions of the contracts from within the same website.

```
    somewhere.com.catalog.v1
      class A
      class B...

    somewhere.com.catalog.v2
      class A
      class B
```

I would like to have a utility program to copy the files from v1, into v2 and change all the namespace references so I don't have to do a manual copy and find & replace.

1. T4 template - need to parameterize this.  I found a [custom templating](http://customtemplating.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex.
2. PowerShell script.  Found [Aaron Lerch's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/aaronlerch/archive/2008/01/04/refactoring-c-with-powershell.aspx) which seems to be close to what I wanted, but I have the worst problems with PowerShell and got a compile error.  I tried downloading some PowerShell extensions for Visual Studio 2010 to get auto-complete but ran into extension conflicts.
3. Razor template.  From what I read it seems to be targeted to single file generation.
4. MSBuild task using the TextTransform utility.
5. Just create a command line C# program that takes in the input folder, output folder and new namespace.
6. Other ***_*__*_*__*_***

Just having trouble choosing the best tool for the job and wanting to learn something new that can be applied in other situations.

Comment: Why don't you properly version your service then just add service references to both new and old.

Comment: @DustinDavis: since this seems an interesting question, can you give us an example of a properly versioned service?

Comment: publish your service. Ex: domain.com/services/2011/05/14/service.svc then update your service as needed and publish again domain.com/services/2011/04/15/service.svc use whatever versioning schem you like. I prefer dates but some ppl hate that. either way just add a new service reference to each from your project and use them as needed. I dont know what changes you made but you could always use an adapter pattern too.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer. It sounds indeed like something the questionasker should do.

Comment: In this case I am the service producer, not consumer, so I need to support two contracts at the same time. I have a breaking change, data type from int/string 
  
`Contracts  
service.v1  
class ARequest  
int Member1  

service.v2  
 class ARequest  
   string Member1  
  
Service  
  .net 4.0 svc-less configuration  
  
Logic  
  v1 => uses v1 contract, but uses adapter pattern to call v2 as @DustinDavis suggested  

  v2 => uses v2 contract  `

The question is since I have 2 contracts I have to expose and lots of classes in contracts, what is best automated way to do this?

Comment: You just use different contract names and then expose endpoint for each contract. Thats the beauty of WCF. Two svc files. v1.svc and v2.svc. If the changes are so that they break then you NEED to version them out. Create shared libraries for common logic then implement your changes in two seperate projects.